# Update every module to the latest resolvable version in a single command?

Tags: composer

I read [Using Composer to Download and Update Files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/install-composer.html) which says I have to type out module names to update them.

Is there command to update every module, for example a plain `composer update`?

Comment: Yes, this is how you should use composer. Drupal is not using it right when they recommend something different. You simply run "composer update". If this doesn't work then check the version restrictions in composer.json and pin a problematic package to a specific version.

Comment: `composer update -W` is usually best for this, as it ensures root dependencies are updated too

Comment: You don't need this if you run the plain "composer update" command, only when updating a single package with dependencies on other packages.

Comment: Thank you! adding the "-W" did the trick!!! For some reason, the plain "composer update" wasn't doing anything.

Comment: It can happen when you have a locked root dependency which another package also depends on at a later version. Might be worth a quick audit of your root dependencies to see if any of them can be removed (i.e. already required by other packages and not needed for custom modules/themes)

Comment: Oftentimes Composer mentions adding `-W` in its output. Was it not?